# root password demo mode Odin

Tags: security

I'm trying to try the Odin demo mode but when I connect to the internet, the system asks me for the password. Could someone please pass it to me? Thank you

Comment: hey there Francesco what password is it asking for exactly?

Comment: How are you connecting to the internet? If it's wireless, then it's your wireless password (often on the bottom of the router). If it's a wired connection, it shouldn't be asking the password. Keep in mind that Odin is unstable and a beta OS, and should be treated as such. I'd look it up personally, but I'm unwilling to pay to test their software or to offer support for their software.